# How to add values in SQL and update it by stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have table name called "`tblBoxStock`" and get the value named `@newQty` and want to add up on top of the current value (column name `currentQty`).

```
Create proc spUpdateQty @newQty int, @boxName nvarchar(20)
as 
Begin 
    Update tblBoxStock
    set currentQty + @newQty = @newQty
    where boxName = @boxName   
End
```

the line

```
set currentQty + @newQty = @newQty
```

shows an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: What error? It looks like nonsense (what value(s)do you want to assign to what variables/fields?)

Answer (score 0):

It should be done like this

```
Update tblBoxStock
set currentQty = currentQty  + isnull(@newQty,0)
where boxName = @boxName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the column value:

```
Update tblBoxStock
    set currentQty = currentQty + @newQty
    where boxName = @boxName;
```

Some databases let you write:

```
Update tblBoxStock
    set currentQty += @newQty
    where boxName = @boxName;
```

I would suggest testing the value to see if the update needs to be done:

```
Update tblBoxStock
    set currentQty = currentQty + @newQty
    where boxName = @boxName and @newQty <> 0;
```